# Celery cannot find a worker

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery, python-2.x, celeryd

I'm using celery with such configuration

```
default_exchange = Exchange('default', type='direct')
latest_exchange = Exchange('latest', type='direct')

shared_celery_config = {
    'BROKER_URL': 'redis://localhost:6379/0',
    'CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND': 'redis://localhost:6379/0',
    'CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE': 'default',
    'CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY': 'default',
    'CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE': 'default',
    'CELERY_QUEUES': (
        Queue('default', default_exchange, routing_key='default'),
        Queue('latest', latest_exchange, routing_key='latest'),
    ),
}

celery = Celery('tasks', config_source=shared_celery_config)
```

But when I'm creating a task none of the worker is consuming it and nothing happens. I  start workers with:
`celery worker -A tasks --loglevel=debug --hostname=worker1`. I can see them from `ps aux | grep celery` output, but when executing some command to get statistics like `celery -A tasks status` I get following error message
**`Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.`**. Therefore all tasks are in *PENDING* status. I believe this is some misconfiguration, but can't figure out what's wrong and how to debug such a thing. Any advise would be very helpful

Comment: My env ```billiard==3.3.0.23 
kombu==3.0.35
celery==3.1.23
```, Python 2.7.6

Comment: When I've upgraded to `billiard==3.5.0.1` I was able to launch command `celery -A tasks status` and received appropriate answer `1 node online.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved. I have an web application which uses gevent and in `tasks` module I have import from another module that has `monkey.patch_all()`. Somehow it prevents billiard and therefore a worker to start pool and that leads to this consequences. 
Anyway, **do not use gevent at all**, imho.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using queues, make sure that at least 1 of your dags is assigned to the worker, meaning - the `AIRFLOW__OPERATORS__DEFAULT_QUEUE` value of the worker's `docker-compose.yaml` file should contain the `default_args['queue']` value of the dag's python file.